# How to add a Spark Dataframe to the bottom of another dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I can use `withcolumn`to add new columns to a Dataframe. But in scala how can I add new rows to a DataFrame?

I'm trying to add a dataframe to the bottom of another one. So either how to add rows in scala or how to add a DataFrame to the bottom of another one will help. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the `unionAll()` function?

Comment: Thanks! unionAll works!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If they have the same schema, simply use [`union`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@union(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) for spark 2+:

```
val dfUnion = df1.union(df2)
```

Or `unionAll` for spark 1+:

```
val dfUnion = df1.unionAll(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thats what I need!

Comment: Since Spark 2.0 `unionAll()` is marked as `deprecated` (@deprecated("use union()", "2.0.0")) - I changed your answer accordingly.

Comment: The question seems to be talking about concatenation ("add a to the bottom of another one"), and just for future searchers: `union` is not the same as concatenation. It doesn't make order guarantees about the combined data.