# Scala: How to join more than one Spark Dataframe by rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

It was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550983/how-to-add-a-spark-dataframe-to-the-bottom-of-another-dataframe) about how to merge two dataframes by rows using `unionAll`.

Is there a way of applying a `unionAll` (or a similar function) on an sequence of dataframes without looping and defining `var`, assuming I don't know the length of the sequence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private def unionAll(dataFrames: Seq[DataFrame], sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = dataFrames match {
  case Nil => sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
  case head :: Nil => head
  case head :: tail => head.unionAll(unionAll(tail, sqlContext))
}
```

The second case is required to prevent trying to union empty DF (which doesn't have the right schema) with a non-empty one.

This *does* assume that if the list isn't empty, all DataFrames share the same schema.